# Webcam is not defined (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, webcam.js

I'm trying to set a webcam settings for some parameters using `ClassName` but the console says `Webcam is not defined`. Could anyone explain me where is my fault ? I already set the variable on it as `attachs[]` but still shows the error. I already browse for the problem too, but I have no idea what to do in my script. Please help..

This is my script :

```
var attachs = document.getElementsByClassName('my_camera');

attachs[0] = Webcam.set({ width: 360, heighht: 300, dest_width: 640, dest_height: 480, image_format: 'jpeg', jpeg_quality: 100 });
attachs[1] = Webcam.set({ width: 360, heighht: 300, dest_width: 640, dest_height: 480, image_format: 'jpeg', jpeg_quality: 100 });
attachs[2] = Webcam.set({ width: 360, heighht: 300, dest_width: 640, dest_height: 480, image_format: 'jpeg', jpeg_quality: 100 });

Webcam.attach(attachs[0]);
Webcam.attach(attachs[1]);
Webcam.attach(attachs[2]);

function take_snapshot(){
    Webcam.snap( function(data_uri){
        var camera = getElementsByClassName('my_camera');
        camera[0].innerHTML = '<h2>Hasil Foto :</h2>' + '<img class="img-responsive" src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
        camera[1].innerHTML = '<h2>Hasil Foto :</h2>' + '<img class="img-responsive" src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
        camera[2].innerHTML = '<h2>Hasil Foto :</h2>' + '<img class="img-responsive" src="'+data_uri+'"/>';

    var raw_image_data = data_uri.replace(/^data\:image\/\w+\);base64\,/, '');

    var mydata = document.getElementsByClassName('mydata');
    mydata[0].value = raw_image_data;
    mydata[1].value = raw_image_data;
    mydata[2].value = raw_image_data;

    var opening = document.getElementsByClassName('opening');
    opening[0].submit();
    opening[1].submit();
    opening[2].submit();

  });
}
```

**EDIT**

This is my whole script as requested before..

```js
// Image Upload preview

$(document).ready( function() {
     $(document).on('change', '.btn-file :file', function() {
  var input = $(this),
   label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
  input.trigger('fileselect', [label]);
  });

  $('.btn-file :file').on('fileselect', function(event, label) {

      var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
          log = label;

      if( input.length ) {
          input.val(log);
      } else {
          if( log ) alert(log);
      }

  });
  function readURL(input) {
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function (e) {
              $('#img-upload').attr('src', e.target.result);
          }

          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
  }

  $("#imgInp").change(function(){
      readURL(this);
  });
 });


//modal-trigger
$('#delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
    $('.debug-url').html('Data URL: <strong>' + $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href') + '</strong>');
});


//liveclock

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(timestamp, 1000);
});

function timestamp() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/dailyreport/function/timestamp.php',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#timestamp').html(data);
        },
    });
}

// Webcam script

require('./Webcam.js');
var attachs = document.getElementsByClassName('my_camera');
attachs[0] = Webcam.set({ width: 360, height: 300, dest_width: 640, dest_height: 480, image_format: 'jpeg', jpeg_quality: 100 });
attachs[1] = Webcam.set({ width: 360, height: 300, dest_width: 640, dest_height: 480, image_format: 'jpeg', jpeg_quality: 100 });
attachs[2] = Webcam.set({ width: 360, height: 300, dest_width: 640, dest_height: 480, image_format: 'jpeg', jpeg_quality: 100 });

Webcam.attach(attachs[0]);
Webcam.attach(attachs[1]);
Webcam.attach(attachs[2]);

function take_snapshot(){
 Webcam.snap( function(data_uri){
  var camera = getElementsByClassName('my_camera');
  camera[0].innerHTML = '<h2>Hasil Foto :</h2>' + '<img class="img-responsive" src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
  camera[1].innerHTML = '<h2>Hasil Foto :</h2>' + '<img class="img-responsive" src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
  camera[2].innerHTML = '<h2>Hasil Foto :</h2>' + '<img class="img-responsive" src="'+data_uri+'"/>';

  var raw_image_data = data_uri.replace(/^data\:image\/\w+\);base64\,/, '');

  var mydata = document.getElementsByClassName('mydata');
  mydata[0].value = raw_image_data;
  mydata[1].value = raw_image_data;
  mydata[2].value = raw_image_data;
  
  var opening = document.getElementsByClassName('opening');
  opening[0].submit();
  opening[1].submit();
  opening[2].submit();

 });
}
```

```html
<?php $title = 'Absen Staff | Soursally Daily Report'; include '../function/view/header.php'; include '../function/core/init.php'; ?>

<?php

    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");

    $waktu   = date('H:i:s');

 ?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Absensi Harian
        <small>
          <?php
            if (($waktu > '07:00:00') && ($waktu < '09:15:00')) {
              echo "Staff Opening";
            } 
            if (($waktu > '12:00:00') && ($waktu < '12:15:00')) {
              echo "Staff Middle";
            }
            if (($waktu > '15:00:00') && ($waktu < '15:15:00')) {
              echo "Staff Closing";
            } ?>
        </small>
      </h1><hr />
  <?php if ((($waktu > '09:15:00') && ($waktu < '12:00:00')) 
      || (($waktu > '12:15:00') && ($waktu < '15:00:00')) 
      ||  ($waktu > '15:15:00') && ($waktu < '23:59:00')
      ||  ($waktu > '00:00:00') && ($waktu < '07:00:00')) { ?>
      <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
        <label for="timestamp">Sekarang Pukul <span id="timestamp"></span></label>
        <h2><b>ABSENSI TIDAK DAPAT DILAKUKAN <hr /></b></h2>
        <h3><b>Waktu sudah melewati rentang yang telah ditentukan.</b></h3>
        <p>Absensi hanya dapat dilakukan sebelum <b>pukul 09 : 15 : 00 untuk shift opening</b> dan <b>15 : 15 : 00 untuk shift closing</b> dan <b>pukul 12 : 15 : 00 untuk middle.</b></p>
        <p>Staff yang tidak melaksanakan absensi & sesi foto bersama sesuai shift masing-masing akan dianggap terlambat, kecuali sudah konfirmasi ke Manager Area sebelumnya</p>
      </div>
     <hr />
  </div>
<?php } ?>

<?php if (($waktu < '09:15:00') && ($waktu > '07:00:00')){ ?>
  <div class="row">
    <form id="opening" action="../function/absen-opening.php" method="post">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="mydata" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="mydata" value="">
        <div id="results"></div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="lokasi-outlet">Lokasi Outlet</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="lokasi-absen" id="lokasi">
            <option value="">Lokasi Outlet</option>

            <?php
            global $conn;
            $query = "SELECT * FROM daftar_outlet ORDER BY lokasi ASC";
            $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
            $current_subcategory = "Jakarta";
            while ($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
              if ($data["lokasi"] != $current_subcategory) {
                if ($current_subcategory != "Jakarta") {
                  echo "</optgroup>";
                }
                echo '<optgroup label="'.$data['lokasi'].'">';
                $current_subcategory = $data['lokasi'];
              }
              echo '<option value="'.$data['id'].'">'.$data['nama_outlet'].'</option>';
            }
            echo "</optgroup>";
            ?>


          </select>
        <label for="staff-opening">Staff Opening</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="staff-opening" placeholder="Contoh : Andi, Riska, Mei (Part time), Wulan (training)" >
        <label for="staff-ijin">Ijin</label>
          <input type="text" name="staff-ijin" class="form-control" placeholder="Contoh : Andika" >
        <label for="staff-cuti">Cuti</label>
          <input type="text" name="staff-cuti" class="form-control" placeholder="Contoh : Feriansyah" >
        <label for="staff-off">Off</label>
          <input type="text" name="staff-libur" class="form-control" placeholder="Contoh : Adrian" >
        <div style="margin-top:20px;">
          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Kirim</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="my_camera" style="background:#000; margin-bottom:5px;"></div>


          <!-- A button for taking snaps -->
          <a class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="button" value="Take Snapshot" onclick="take_snapshot()">Ambil Foto</a>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
<?php } ?>

<?php if (($waktu < '12:15:00') && ($waktu > '12:00:00')){ ?>
  <div class="row">
    <form action="../function/absen-middle.php" method="post">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="mydata2" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="mydata" value="">
        <div id="results"></div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="lokasi-outlet">Lokasi Outlet</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="lokasi-absen" id="lokasi">
            <option value="">Lokasi Outlet</option>

            <?php
            global $conn;
            $query = "SELECT * FROM daftar_outlet ORDER BY lokasi ASC";
            $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
            $current_subcategory = "Jakarta";
            while ($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
              if ($data["lokasi"] != $current_subcategory) {
                if ($current_subcategory != "Jakarta") {
                  echo "</optgroup>";
                }
                echo '<optgroup label="'.$data['lokasi'].'">';
                $current_subcategory = $data['lokasi'];
              }
              echo '<option value="'.$data['nama_outlet'].'">'.$data['nama_outlet'].'</option>';
            }
            echo "</optgroup>";
            ?>


          </select>
        <label for="staff-middle">Staff Middle</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="staff-opening" placeholder="Contoh : Andi, Riska, Mei (Part time), Wulan (training)" >
          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Kirim</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="my_camera" style="background:#000; margin-bottom:5px;"></div>


          <!-- A button for taking snaps -->
          <a class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="button" value="Take Snapshot" onclick="take_snapshot()">Ambil Foto</a>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>

<?php if (($waktu < '15:15:00') && ($waktu > '15:00:00')){ ?>
  <div class="row">
    <form action="../function/absen-closing.php" method="post">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="mydata3" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="mydata" value="">
        <div id="results"></div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="lokasi-outlet">Lokasi Outlet</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="lokasi-absen" id="lokasi">
            <option value="">Lokasi Outlet</option>

            <?php
            global $conn;
            $query = "SELECT * FROM daftar_outlet ORDER BY lokasi ASC";
            $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
            $current_subcategory = "Jakarta";
            while ($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
              if ($data["lokasi"] != $current_subcategory) {
                if ($current_subcategory != "Jakarta") {
                  echo "</optgroup>";
                }
                echo '<optgroup label="'.$data['lokasi'].'">';
                $current_subcategory = $data['lokasi'];
              }
              echo '<option value="'.$data['nama_outlet'].'">'.$data['nama_outlet'].'</option>';
            }
            echo "</optgroup>";
            ?>


          </select>
        <label for="staff-middle">Staff Sore</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="staff-opening" placeholder="Contoh : Andi, Riska, Mei (Part time), Wulan (training)" >
          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Kirim</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="my_camera" style="background:#000; margin-bottom:5px;"></div>


          <!-- A button for taking snaps -->
          <a class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="button" value="Take Snapshot" onclick="take_snapshot()">Ambil Foto</a>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>

</div>


<?php include '../function/view/footer.php'; ?>
```

**EDIT again**

Sorry, i forgot to include the footer.php script

here it is..

```
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/webcam.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well the variable `Webcam` is definitely not defined in the code you posted. You probably expected it to be imported from somewhere else, and forgot to do the import or forget to put in a `<script>` tag before the one enclosing this code.

Comment: This looks like WebcamJS code, maybe [this demo helps you](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/blob/master/demos/basic.html)

Comment: Ray Toal said it before me but I'll say it again, Webcam is not defined in the above code. If Ciro Spaciari is right and it's WebcamJS code, are you including that script BEFORE you run your own code?

Comment: you also type `heighht` instead of `height`

Comment: Yes, it was WebcamJS code, but i modified it and place it in the external JS file so it doesn't mess the HTML script and make it more readable. anyways, thanks for the answers and the correction sir, i'll try to do an edit on my script.

Comment: i think the right syntax for require is `var Webcam = require('')` but it not native too. add the script as a script tag instead, before you execute your code.

Comment: seeing the footer now you also need to put webcam.js before main.js

Comment: allright, let me try sir..

Comment: it works! thanks a lot sir.. :D

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Webcam is not native in browser you need to import a script/library. Like [WebcamJS](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/blob/master/demos/basic.html).

The script must be added before you run your own code or you will get this error.

**EDIT**

Seeing the footer now you also need to put webcam.js before main.js

Comment: but i already called the script on the HTML script, sir. Do i have to call it on the JS file itself ? just like an "include" function on PHP ?

Comment: can you edit/post your html and full script? so we can run and simulate the problem.